# Memory spike with Xpath in Foreach Loop in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, memory-leaks, domxpath

I have been using an Xpath object and recently found it was the root cause of my memory spike. I define my xpath object

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom ->loadHTML($cl);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

Here is a bit of the code causing the memory to continually increase:

```
$websiteQuery = $xpath->query("//a[@compid='Profile_Website']/@href");
foreach($websiteQuery as $web){
    $website = $websiteQuery ->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

This causes a never ending memory increase until the script finished (sometimes over 6 hours long). In this case, $websiteQuery->length is only 1, so it only goes through the loop once, but somehoe calling $websiteQuery->item(0) within the loop causes the memory spike. This is a solution:

```
$websiteQuery = $xpath->query("//a[@compid='Profile_Website']/@href");
foreach($websiteQuery as $web){
    $website = $web->nodeValue;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Sure second form is more standard. “This is a solution” means that it is work fine for you?

Comment: nodeValue and value actually return the same value, but I edited it to avoid confusion. And yes, the solution works and no longer increases memory, but I am still wondering why the memory spike for the first way of doing it @fusion3k

Comment: You have an extended `DOMDocument` class? I don't have `->value` property in `DOMNode/DOmElemen`...

Comment: I guess I must, since value is definitely an option and almost always is the equivalent to nodeValue @fusion3k

Comment: First of all, if your memory-hungry code is correct, it will return always same node. The correct syntax for it is using a `for` loop, not a `foreach`. I don't know why your issue happen, I only can guess something about internal pointer, but I have not idea on how DOMDocument is built. Can you try through a `for` loop to see if the problem remain? `for( $i = 0; $i < $websiteQuery->length; $i++ )` I still can't get over the `->value` :) :)

Comment: I will try with for and see what happens @fusion3k